# How to calculate the modulus of a complex number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I know that for an equation of real numbers you could calculate the modulus as follows (if I am not mistaking):

$$ x = a + b$$
$$|x| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

But now I found this equation with this result:

$$|K| = |1-\cos 2k(L-x)+j \sin 2k(L-x)| = \\
\sqrt{(1+ \cos^ 2 2k(L-x)-2\cos 2k(L-x)+ \sin^2 2k(L-x))} = \\
\sqrt{2-2\cos 2k(L-x)}$$

Could someone please explain me how they got that result and what formula they may have used?

Comment: In this case $K$ is of the form $K=a+jb$, where $a=1-\cos2k(L-x),b=\sin2k(L-x)$. Hence 
\begin{eqnarray}
|K| & = & \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
& = & \sqrt{1-2\cos2k(L-x)+\cos^22k(L-x)+\sin^22k(L-x)}\\
& = & \sqrt{1-2\cos2k(L-x)+1}
\end{eqnarray}
where in the last line we used $\sin^2\theta +\cos^2\theta=1$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: @NateRiver, from where does $2cos2k(L-x)$ come? Add this as an answer and I ll approve it :)

Comment: It's the term $-2xy$ in $(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2$.

Comment: By the way, for *real* numbers you definitely *not* compute the modulus the way you wrote...

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value of a complex number is
$$|a + j b| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

So you have

$$|K| = \sqrt{ (1 - \cos 2k(L-x))^2 + (\sin 2k(L-x))^2 }$$

Algebraically expanding gives your second line, then the third line is found by the identity

$$ \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1 $$

Comment: I think the result u provided does not equal the result u provided...